# Как сделать разсылку уведомлений когда приложение закрыто и удалено с RAM

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

```
   package com.frusty.cooking.services;

import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.app.job.JobParameters;
import android.app.job.JobService;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.frusty.cooking.R;
import com.frusty.cooking.broadcasts.ClearNotificationPullBroadcast;
import com.frusty.cooking.broadcasts.CloseNotification;
import com.frusty.cooking.entity.Notification;
import com.frusty.cooking.entity.Time;
import com.frusty.cooking.entity.User;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

public class NotificationService extends Service {
    private static String TAG="NotificationServices";
    User user;
    String userID;

    public NotificationService() {
    }



    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("ServiceSS", "Started");


        userID = intent.getStringExtra("user_id");
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").orderByChild("id").equalTo(userID);
                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        Log.d("ServiceSS","Update, user id: "+userID);
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            user = null;
                            user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                            int id = 0;

                            ArrayList<Notification> notifications = user.getNotifications_pool();
                            for (Notification notification : notifications) {
                                id++;
                                createNotification(id, notification);
                            }

                        }
                        query.removeEventListener(this);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });


        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void createNotification(int id, Notification notification) {
        String title = notification.getTitle();
        String body = notification.getMessageBody();
        String recipe_id = notification.getRecipe_id();
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name= "Cooking";
            String description = "Cooking";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("Cooking", name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent( this, ClearNotificationPullBroadcast.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("user_id", userID);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("recipe_id", recipe_id);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("notification_pull_id", notification.getId());
        notificationIntent.putExtra("notification_id", id);

        Intent closeNotification = new Intent(this, CloseNotification.class);

        closeNotification.putExtra("user_id", userID);
        closeNotification.putExtra("recipe_id", recipe_id);
        closeNotification.putExtra("notification_pull_id", notification.getId());
        closeNotification.putExtra("notification_id", id);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent. getBroadcast (this, 0 , notificationIntent , PendingIntent. FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT ) ;
        PendingIntent pClose = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, closeNotification, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "Cooking")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_logo_round)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_logo_round)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setDeleteIntent(pClose)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setOngoing(false);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_logo_round);
            mBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.main));
        } else {
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_logo_round);
        }
        mNotificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
      
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("ServiceSS", "Stop");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);

    }
}
```

С помощью Firebase Database я получаю пул уведомлений пользователя, если есть оповещения, тогда выводится это оповещение, через бродкаст я открываю или закрываю оповещения и удаляю это оповещение из пула.

Вопрос в следующем. Как сделать так же как в телеграмме или вайбере. Когда приложение закрыто и удалено в оперативной памяти, оповещения приходят.
Что перепробовал:

```
startForeground();
startForegroundService();
```

Пробовал перезапускать сервис в onTaskRemoved(), или onDestroy();
Все варианти не работают, так как Андроид думает что сервис бесполезен и убивает полностю поток.
Рылся в исходнике Телеграма, и нашол то что он использует кастомный NotificationCenter и я не понимаю как он работает.
Больше ничево не нашол. Вот почему я здесь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут два варианта решения:

1. создать службу которая будет работать постоянно, даже после закрытия приложения.
   Главный минус - это не скрываемое уведомление в шторке, о том что служба работает без активити. Без нее у тебя в фоне служба работать не будет. Выглядит это примерно так.

   ```
   private void startService_NOT_STICKY(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = getPackageName();
        String channelName = "Service Channel name";
        NotificationChannel chan = new 
        NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, 
        channelName, 
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = 
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_info_black_24dp)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("Служба запущена")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .build();
        startForeground(2, notification);
    }
    else
    {
       createPersistentNotification(
       getApplicationContext(), this);
    }
    }
   ```
2. Использовать FCM.
   Если тебе нужно чтобы андроид отображал уведомления без служб когда приложение не запущено, то Firebase Realtime Database это не то что тебе нужно, тебе нужен Firebase Cloud Messaging.
   И "серверная часть", которая будет рассылать сообщение в топик / или на устройство по идентификатору при возникновении определенного события в системе. На этапе тестирования можно рассылать уведомления через  консоль FCM.

Если решишься то нужно build.gardle (app) добавить

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.x.x'
```

В манифесте добавить обработку события от FCM

```
    <service
        android:name=".CloudMessageService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Создать наследника FirebaseMessagingService

```
public class CloudMessageService extends FirebaseMessagingService{
    public CloudMessageService() {
    }

   @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Intent intent;
        boolean localMessageDelivered = false;
        try {
            if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
                sendNotification(this, remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()); // тут твое уведомление. 
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я читал документацию про Firebase Cloud Messaging, там сказано что рассылки не будет приъодит еслки приложение удалено с оперативки. Я бы сделал через Firebase Cloud Messaging если бы мне подходило. Ну и кслову, как задать маленькую иконку в Notification

так как 
`
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_logo_round);
            mBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.main));
        } else {
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_logo_round);
        }
`
Не работает

Comment: ну если запустить фоновую службу, то будет всегда приходить, причем если посылать только data, то приходит всегда, даже если службы нет. потом внутри можно фоновый сервис запустить или послать интент в мейн, и остальное уже ему отдавать на обработку. т.к. если оно долго выполняется то его фцм прибивает. а вот просто нотификейшн не приходит. тут еще зависит от того куда ты его шлешь, если в to, то токен изменится, а приложение закрыто и о изменении токена сервер оно не уведомит, а если в топик общий к примеру  "updates" то дойдет.

Comment: Можете дать пример, я не доконца понимаю алгоритм, если вы про бродкаст то я пробовал через fmc и они не приходили даже если запускать фоновый процес. Надеюсь на исходник примера.

Comment: он большой. не думаю что здесь он уместен. могу залить на пастбин

Comment: Было бы отлияно.